# Is there a roaming settings equivalate in Teams app?

Tags: javascript, office-js, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm working on a Team App using MicrosoftTeams.js, the issue is when a user leaves the app all the data is lost.

On Office.js there is an tool Roaming Settings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.roamingsettings?view=outlook-js-preview), which form prior use is exactly what I need.

So my question is, is there a Roaming Settings equivalent on MicrosoftTeams.js or is localStorage reliable on Teams desktop.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on it. What kind of data you want to store?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT This idea was to store the users last visited web-page so that I could auto-redirect them back to it. As, as soon as the user leaves the Teams app and reopens it they are thrown back to the landing page.

Comment: Currently it's not possible to do this. You can suggest this feature here: [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to store the users last visited web-page so that I could auto-redirect them back to it. As, as soon as the user leaves the Teams app and reopens it they are thrown back to the landing page.

You can suggest this feature here: [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)